# UWP - CheckBox or Button is not visible

Tags: c#, uwp, winui, winui-3

**Using**

Jetbrains **Rider**

**U**niversal **W**indows **P**latform

**Problem**

The window is visible, but the buttons are not visible.

**Question**

How can I fix the problem?

**Source code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace UWP_TEST1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            
            StackPanel stackPanel1 = new StackPanel();
            CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox();
            checkBox1.Content = "I agree to the terms of service.";
            
            stackPanel1.Children.Add(checkBox1);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `stackPanel1` must either be declared in XAML, like `<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1"/>`, or you have to set the Window's Content like `Content = stackPanel1;`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the StackPanel `stackPanel1` to the page. Setting the content of your page to the `stackPanel1` will show the buttons. You can do this by adding `Content=stackPanel` in the constructor.